# DeserializationException is not handled correctly with current DLT config

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka, kafka-dlt

I am using spring-kafka 3.0.4 and AWS infrastructure. I want to configure retries and DLT properly but I am facing some issues when handling DeserializationExceptions.
Some of my Kafka config includes:

```
    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, Object> consumerFactory() {
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(
                kafkaConsumerProps,
                StringDeserializer::new,
                () -> new ErrorHandlingDeserializer<>(kafkaAwsGlueValueDeserializer()),
                false
        );
    }

    @Bean
    public DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer(KafkaTemplate<String, Object> kafkaTemplate) {
        DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<String, byte[]> defaultKafkaProducerFactory =
                new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(kafkaProperties.buildProducerProperties(), new StringSerializer(),
                        new ByteArraySerializer());
        KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> bytesKafkaTemplate = new KafkaTemplate<>(defaultKafkaProducerFactory);

        Map<Class<?>, KafkaOperations<?, ?>> templates = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        templates.put(Object.class, kafkaTemplate);
        templates.put(byte[].class, bytesKafkaTemplate);
        DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer deadLetterPublishingRecoverer = new DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer(templates);
        return deadLetterPublishingRecoverer;
    }
```

I also configured RetryTopicConfiguration bean with some custom properties and specify handle method for it and provided kafka template that uses GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaSerializer.

Everything works nicely if exception is thrown when processing message in specific consumer.
As I understood, when DeserializationException is thrown null value is passed to DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer and ByteArraySerializer should be used to produce record for my DLT topic. However I can see that for some reason GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaSerializer is used to produce message for my DLT for bad message and it fails and blocks my consumer:

```
2023-08-31T09:06:47.952Z ERROR 1 --- [ntainer#6-0-C-1] k.r.DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory : Record: topic = test.TestData, partition = 1, offset = 0, main topic = test.TestData threw an error at topic test.TestData and won't be retried. Sending to DLT with name test.TestData-test-dlt.
org.springframework.kafka.listener.ListenerExecutionFailedException: Listener failed
...
Caused by: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.DeserializationException: failed to deserialize
...
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.exception.AWSSchemaRegistryException: Exception occurred while de-serializing Avro message
    ...
    at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.deserializers.GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaDeserializer.deserialize(GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaDeserializer.java:116) ~[schema-registry-serde-1.1.15.jar!/:na]
    at org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer.deserialize(Deserializer.java:60) ~[kafka-clients-3.3.2.jar!/:na]
    at org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer.deserialize(ErrorHandlingDeserializer.java:179) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
    ... 15 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroTypeException: Found test.avro.TestData, expecting test.avro.TestData, missing required field testId
    ...
2023-08-31T09:06:47.955Z  WARN 1 --- [ntainer#6-0-C-1] r.DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory$1 : Destination resolver returned non-existent partition test.TestData-test-dlt-1, KafkaProducer will determine partition to use for this topic
2023-08-31T09:06:47.955Z ERROR 1 --- [ntainer#6-0-C-1] c.a.s.schemaregistry.utils.AVROUtils     : Unsupported Avro Data Formats
2023-08-31T09:06:47.956Z ERROR 1 --- [ntainer#6-0-C-1] c.a.s.schemaregistry.utils.AVROUtils     : Unsupported Type of Record received
2023-08-31T09:06:47.956Z ERROR 1 --- [ntainer#6-0-C-1] r.DeadLetterPublishingRecovererFactory$1 : Dead-letter publication to test.TestData-test-dlt failed for: test.TestData-1@0
com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.exception.AWSSchemaRegistryException: Unsupported Type of Record received
    ...
    at com.amazonaws.services.schemaregistry.serializers.GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaSerializer.prepareInput(GlueSchemaRegistryKafkaSerializer.java:157) 
2023-08-31T09:06:47.957Z ERROR 1 --- [ntainer#6-0-C-1] o.s.kafka.listener.DefaultErrorHandler   : Failed to determine if this record (test.TestData-1@0) should be recovererd, including in seeks
org.springframework.kafka.KafkaException: Dead-letter publication to test.TestData-test-dlt failed for:test.TestData-1@0
    at org.springframework.kafka.listener.DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.verifySendResult(DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer.java:669) ~[spring-kafka-3.0.4.jar!/:3.0.4]
    ...
```

What is wrong with my configuration?

I've tried to use different configurations but without success

Answer (score 0):

Use a `DelegatingByTypeSerializer`

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#by-type

> Version 2.8 introduced the `DelegatingByTypeSerializer`.

```java
@Bean
public ProducerFactory<Integer, Object> producerFactory(Map<String, Object> config) {
    return new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(config,
            null, new DelegatingByTypeSerializer(Map.of(
                    byte[].class, new ByteArraySerializer(),
                    Bytes.class, new BytesSerializer(),
                    String.class, new StringSerializer())));
}
```

> Starting with version 2.8.3, you can configure the serializer to check if the map key is assignable from the target object, useful when a delegate serializer can serialize sub classes. In this case, if there are ambiguous matches, an ordered `Map`, such as a `LinkedHashMap` should be provided.

or use a `DelegatingByTopicSerializer`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#by-topic

The latter can be configured with properties; the `DelegatingByTypeSerializer` must be injected into the producer factory either via a constructor or setter.

Comment: Thank you for answer Gary :) I suppose when using first one for common producerFactory I can use default DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer? When testing this locally I can see that bad message produce couple logs. First one is the same as previously(as expected). Second one contains same stack trace and similar error message "...threw error at topic dlt and won't be retied. No further action will be..." so the issue is DLT consumer I suppose and last one says "No destination returned for record dlt..." Do I need to provide some additional config to DLT listeners so RetryTopicConfiguration bean?

Comment: The DLT consumer needs to accept `Object` so it can receive errors of both types; or you can use a custom destination resolver to send deserialization exceptions to a different DLT.